# Shaping input for a coremlmodel

Tags: ios, coreml, onnx-coreml

I have a coremlmodel taking an input of shape `MultiArray (Float32 67 x 256 x 320)`
I am having a hard time to shape the input to this model. 
Currently, I am trying to achieve it like so,

```
var m = try! MLMultiArray(shape: [67,256,320], dataType: .double)
for i in 0...66{           
    var cost = rand((256,320)) // this is coming from swix [SWIX]
    memcpy(m.dataPointer+i*256*320, &cur_cost.flat.grid , 256*320)
}
```

I will have to replace the rand with matrices of that size later. I am using this for testing purposes first.

Any pointers on how to mould input to fit the volume would be greatly appreciated..

[[SWIX](https://github.com/stsievert/swix)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be wrong in your code is that you're copying bytes instead of doubles. A double is 8 bytes, so your offset should be `i*256*320*MemoryLayout<Double>.stride` and the amount you're copying should be `256*320*MemoryLayout<Double>.stride`.

Note that you can also use the MLMultiArray's `strides` property to compute the offset for a given data element in the array:

```
let offset = i0 * strides[0].intValue + i1 * strides[1].intValue + i2 * strides[2].intValue
```

Comment: I just saw that from your repo on github with CoreMLHelpers. Thanks. However, a follow up question- Any way to access the arrays by indices? eg., m[1] = array(256,320) etc., like in numpy m[1,:,:] will give the first slice of the volume

Comment: That would be nice to have, but for now you'll have to do the "slicing" by hand, by computing the offset of where that slice would begin.